# Method Definition (inside of an Abstract Controller class) with no statements inside method code block returns call to itself how?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Inside ASP.NET CORE MVC source code from github.

I could not understand that , no statements are present inside method body,even then method returns a call to itself how ???
How Syntactically ?

How semantically ?

& How logically ???

```
public virtual ViewResult View()
{
    return View(viewName: null);
}
```

This method is declared inside an Abstract class named Controller.

Link to the Source code
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/Controller.cs

Answer (score 0):

It calls an overload that has a viewName argument.

```
public virtual ViewResult View(string? viewName)
{
    return View(viewName, model: ViewData.Model);
}
```